# I can't see perf's power/energy-cores option for measure power consumption

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, perf, energy

My system use Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold processor and Centos, Linux kernel 5.5.2  version

perf version output is `5.5.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64`

I won't get the power consumption of each core.
so I tried this.

```
>>>  sudo perf stat -a -r 1 -e "power/energy-cores/" ./run
event syntax error: 'power/energy-cores/'
                           \___ unknown term

valid terms: event,config,config1,config2,name,period,percore

Initial error:
event syntax error: 'power/energy-cores/'
                           \___ unknown term

valid terms: event,config,config1,config2,name,period,percore
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events

 Usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]

    -e, --event <event>   event selector. use 'perf list' to list available event
```

As you can see, an error occurred.

So I looked in `/sys/bus/event_source/devices/power/events` directory  to see what events were here.

under results.

```
>>> ls /sys/bus/event_source/devices/power/events

energy-pkg  energy-pkg.scale  energy-pkg.unit  energy-ram  energy-ram.scale  energy-ram.unit
```

I can't see the `power/energy-cores` option.
I just have only a `power/energy-pkg` and `power/energy-ram` option.

and some people had `power/energy-gpu`.

How can get `energy-cores` and `energy-gpu`?

```
>>> perf list | grep energy
  power/energy-pkg/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
  power/energy-ram/                                  [Kernel PMU event]


>>> sudo perf stat -a -r 1 -e "power/energy-pkg/" -e "power/energy-ram/" ./run
6765
 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

              0.06 Joules power/energy-pkg/
              0.01 Joules power/energy-ram/

       0.001452589 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perf` has added an uncore PMU to expose the Intel RAPL energy consumption counters. The events `power/energy-cores` and `power/gpu` in `perf` are mapped to the RAPL domains **PP0** and **PP1** respectively. You can see this [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/arch/x86/events/intel/rapl.c#L516).

```
static struct perf_msr rapl_msrs[] = {
    [PERF_RAPL_PP0]  = { MSR_PP0_ENERGY_STATUS,      &rapl_events_cores_group, test_msr },
    [PERF_RAPL_PKG]  = { MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS,      &rapl_events_pkg_group,   test_msr },
    [PERF_RAPL_RAM]  = { MSR_DRAM_ENERGY_STATUS,     &rapl_events_ram_group,   test_msr },
    [PERF_RAPL_PP1]  = { MSR_PP1_ENERGY_STATUS,      &rapl_events_gpu_group,   test_msr },
    [PERF_RAPL_PSYS] = { MSR_PLATFORM_ENERGY_STATUS, &rapl_events_psys_group,  test_msr },
};
```

To read about RAPL domains, please visit the Intel Software Developers Manual Vol 3b (Chapter on Power and Thermal management).

Each of these domains come with their own architectural capabilities. These capabilities will be indicated by presence of certain non-architectural MSRs in the processor. But the presence of these domains vary across different Intel processor model types. Some processor models will support all of these domains, some will only support a few.

`perf` tries to probe for these RAPL MSRs and creates a `rapl_model_match` device table based on the model of the processor, following the msr and cstate module design.

A snapshot of this is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/arch/x86/events/intel/rapl.c#L718).

For example, you can see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/arch/x86/events/intel/rapl.c#L703) that only the domains **Package** and **DRAM** are supported.

```
static struct rapl_model model_knl = {
    .events     = BIT(PERF_RAPL_PKG) |
                  BIT(PERF_RAPL_RAM),
    .apply_quirk    = true,
};
```

So, in order to get the other events, you would have to use a system having a **different processor model**, thereby ensuring the presence of all the relevant RAPL MSRs. You cannot just build support into your existing system to magically use the `energy-cores` and `gpu` events.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can get many detail and principle of perf and know where i find in linux kernel code for my perf domain.
thanks for vary much. :)

Comment: I have another Question.
How to change MSR register contents? I find one solution using  'MSR-Tool'
there are another way change MSR register beside using MSR-Tool?

Comment: You can use [wrmsr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/wrmsr.1.html) besides MSR-Tool.